# NSArray of NSStrings that an array contains object(s) starting with string

Tags: ios, search, filter, nsstring, nsarray

I am trying to find all objects inside an array of NSStrings that start with a specific string, and return a smaller array containing all of those objects. For example, you could have an array with the objects:

```
'Cat',
'Dog',
'Dolphin',
'Whale'
```

And when the string it searching is `do`, a new NSArray is returned with the `Dog` and `Dolphin` objects only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSString* beginsWithRequirement = @"do";
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", beginsWithRequirement];
NSArray* subArray = [originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

For more information on using predicates, see the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1).

Comment: that was so freaking funky. I had to add "SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@" and not just use plain old %@.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
-(NSArray *)entriesInArray:(NSArray *)wordsArray whichStartWithString:(NSString *)startString {

    startString = [startString lowercaseString]; // get rid of this for case-sensitive (& the lowercaseString bit in the loop too)
    NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *thisString in wordsArray) {
        if ([[thisString lowercaseString] hasPrefix:startString]) [resultsArray addObject:thisString];
    }

    return resultsArray;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with NSPredicate:

```
 NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dog", 
                                          @"Cat", 
                                          @"Dolphin", 
                                          @"Tiger", nil];
 NSString *search = @"do";
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@", search];
 NSArray *result = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

For more information you can check the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)